# Jquery: Form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am very new to Jquery and hope you guys can help me with this jquery validation problem.

Been trying to validate the form but it does not validate at all. It accepts anything that I type in the field, regardless of what restrictions I set.

Please help. Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#form').validate({
    alert("bbbb");
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
            maxlength: 20,
            lettersonly: true
        },
        ssn: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 9,
            maxlength: 9,
            nowhitespace: true
        },
        gender: {
            required: true
        },
        mobile: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 13,
            digits: true
        },
        address: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Please enter your name",
            minlength: "Name should be more than 2 characters",
            maxlength: "Name should be less than 20 characters",
            lettersonly: "Name should contain only letters"
            },
        ssn: {
            required: "Please enter your NRIC",
            minlength: "NRIC should be more than 9 characters",
            maxlength: "NRIC should be less than 9 characters",
            nowhitespace: "NRIC should not have any spaces"
            },
        gender: {
            required: "Please select your gender",
            },
        mobile: {
            required: "Please enter your mobile number",
            minlength: "Mobile number should be more than 10 characters",
            maxlength: "Mobile number should be less than 13 characters",
            digits: "Mobile number should contain only digits"
            },
        address: {
            required: "Please enter your address",
            minlength: "Address should be more than 10 characters",
            },
        email: {
            required: "Please enter your email address",
            minlength: "Password should be more than 6 characters",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
    },
    });

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $("#form").submit();
        return false;
        });

    });
    </script>

    <div id="form">
    <center>
    <form id="form">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="nric" id="nric" placeholder="NRIC" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <select class="dropdown" id="gender" onChange="changeColor(this)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
    </div>
    <input id="submit" class="button" type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: what's `alert("bbbb");` doing there, in the validation object ? Please remove it, or do that before the `.validate()`

Comment: you cannot have multiple elements with same value for id attribute. And like karel said, you cannot put function inside a javascript object like this. You're passing a javascript object to the validate function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have 2 elements with the `id="form"`, so the validator is assigned to the `div` not to the `form`.

Change the `id` value of the `div` to something else.

Also the `additional-methods.js` file must be added after `query.validate.js` and there is a syntax error because of the `alert()` within the `validate` so

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>
<div>
    <center>
        <form id="form">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" name="nric" id="nric" placeholder="NRIC" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <select class="dropdown" id="gender" onChange="changeColor(this)">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
            </div>
            <input id="submit" class="button" type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </center>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#form').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 20,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            ssn: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 9,
                maxlength: 9,
                nowhitespace: true
            },
            gender: {
                required: true
            },
            mobile: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength: 13,
                digits: true
            },
            address: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your name",
                minlength: "Name should be more than 2 characters",
                maxlength: "Name should be less than 20 characters",
                lettersonly: "Name should contain only letters"
            },
            ssn: {
                required: "Please enter your NRIC",
                minlength: "NRIC should be more than 9 characters",
                maxlength: "NRIC should be less than 9 characters",
                nowhitespace: "NRIC should not have any spaces"
            },
            gender: {
                required: "Please select your gender",
            },
            mobile: {
                required: "Please enter your mobile number",
                minlength: "Mobile number should be more than 10 characters",
                maxlength: "Mobile number should be less than 13 characters",
                digits: "Mobile number should contain only digits"
            },
            address: {
                required: "Please enter your address",
                minlength: "Address should be more than 10 characters",
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email address",
                minlength: "Password should be more than 6 characters",
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/E33HH/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to create custom rule in the library 
like this

```
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function(value, element, arg){
  return arg != value;
}
```

and then have use it like this

```
    rules: {
        gender: {valueNotEquals: "default"}                                             
    },
    messages: {
        gender: { valueNotEquals: "Please select a payment method"}           

    }
```