# Form all fields validation is not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have one form which has **Name, Phone, Hobbies(Drop down), Sex(Radio), Comment & Policy(Checkbox)** now I have to configure validation with different condition.

Conditions:

1. By default **Register Button** should disable
2. After enter details to Name, Phone, Hobbies(Drop down), Sex(Radio), Comment & Policy(Checkbox) **Register Button** need to activate
3. If I uncheck **Policy(Checkbox)** then **Register Button** should disable
4. If **Policy(Checkbox)** is checked and some one remove name or changed any field then **Register Button** should disable

I have following code for doing this task, but it's working separately only for **Name and Phone** or separately If I click on **Policy checkbox I accept**

What am I missing here?

```js
$('form input, form textarea').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;

    $('form input, form textarea').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        // alert("Hello");
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable input
    } else {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled'); // enable input
    }

});

$('#policy').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#register').removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled'); // disable input
    } else {
        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <br>

    <label for="phone">Phone *</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <br>

    <label for="hobbies">Hobbies *</label>
    <select id="hobbies">
        <option> Select </option>
        <option> Bike riding </option>
        <option> Car driving </option>
    </select>    
    <br>
    
    Gender  *
    <label for="male"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="male"> Male</label>
    <label for="female"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="female"> Female</label>
    <br><br> 
    
    Age  *
    <label for="below18"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="below18"> Below or Equal 18</label>
    <label for="above18"><input type="radio" name="sex" id="above18"> Above 18</label>
    <br>

    <label for="comment">Comment *</label>
    <textarea id="comment"> </textarea>
    <br>

    <hr>
    <label for="policy"><input type="checkbox" name="policy" id="policy"> I accept  *</label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" disabled="disabled">

</form>
```

Comment: So why is it two checks and not just one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery: Form validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590396/jquery-form-validation-not-working)